# C# windows service nested Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, windows-services, parallel.foreach

I developed a windows service that queries 70 databases every 5 seconds. For each entry in the database, the data is fetched and written to a .xml file on the file system. The goal of this service is to process the data of each database in a timely fashion. Every now and then, over 9000 entries are created at once in the queuing table. Only 6 databases are activated right now.

There are two sections:
there is one foreach loop for the databases and one for the queuing table in each database. Also, the processed entries are limited to 200 in order that the databases are processed after each other.

The following code snippet shows the OnStart() method of the windows service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    mainTask = new Task(PollQueue, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None);
    mainTask.Start();
}
```

Due to time-sensitive reasons the calls shall be parallelised. The outer loop that iterates over the databases was changed to Parallel.ForEach(). This worked fine for the 6 databases that are already active. Afterwards, the inner loop iterating over the queuing table was also changed to the Parallel.ForEach().

As long as only one database is active, this works, too. But as soon as another is activated, the processing stagnates. Limiting the number of threads with MaxDegreeOfParallelism did not help. Without this limit the number of threads was round about 200. But only one single database was processed.

Here is a code example. The method HandleQueueForEachLoop shows the first implementation and the method HandleQueueForEachParallel the test with Parallel.ForEach. This example is not executable but shows the actuall implementation.

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HandleQueueForEachLoop();
            HandleQueueForEachParallel();
        }

        public static void HandleQueueForEachLoop()
        {
            NameValueCollection branches = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Branches");
            foreach (var branch in branches.AllKeys)
            {
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(branch))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var queue = ReadQueue(QueueEntityDescriptor, conn, MaximumRows);
                    if (queue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        List< DefaultEntity> entitiesWithData = FetchQueueData(queue, conn);
                        foreach (var entity in entitiesWithData)
                        {
                            if (entity.Records.Count == 0)
                            {
                                UpdateQueue(entity.EntityQueueId, QueueEntityDescriptor, conn, EntityQueueErrorEnum.NoRecordsInSelect);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    List<XElement> entityXml = CreateXmlForEntity(entity);
                                    var path = XmlPath;
                                    if (XMLPathSubFolder)
                                    {
                                        path = path + entity.EntityName + "\\";
                                    }

                                    foreach (var item in entityXml)
                                    {
                                        WriteDataXml(item, path, ".work");
                                    }

                                    UpdateQueue(entity.EntityQueueId, EntityQueueErrorEnum.Handled);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    UpdateQueue(entity.EntityQueueId, EntityQueueErrorEnum.Exception);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void HandleQueueForEachParallel()
        {
            NameValueCollection branches = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Branches");
            Parallel.ForEach(branches.AllKeys, branch =>
            {
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(branch))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var queue = ReadQueue(QueueEntityDescriptor, conn, MaximumRows);
                    if (queue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(queue,
                        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 2.0)) },
                        queueItem =>
                        {
                            DefaultEntity entity = FetchQueueEntryData(queueItem, conn);
                            if (entity.Records.Count == 0)
                            {
                                UpdateQueue(entity.EntityQueueId, EntityQueueErrorEnum.NoRecordsInSelect);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    var entityXml = CreateXmlForEntity(entity);
                                    var path = XmlPath;
                                    if (XMLPathSubFolder)
                                    {
                                        path = path + entity.EntityName + "\\";
                                    }

                                    foreach (var item in entityXml)
                                    {
                                        WriteData(item, path, ".work");
                                    }

                                    UpdateQueue(entity.EntityQueueId, EntityQueueErrorEnum.Handled);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    UpdateQueue(entity.EntityQueueId, EntityQueueErrorEnum.Exception);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The server has 4 CPU cores that are hardly used to capacity. We only create one connection for each database with the NuGet package OracleManageDataAccess. The .xml files are written with XElement.Save().

I already read a lot about Parallel.ForEach() and searched through several tutorials.

**My Questions:**

1. Is it wise to use nested Parallel.ForEach loops?
2. Is there any other best practice for parallel processing multiple databases?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by activated. also there is no code so its impossible to see what if any problem you might be having,

Comment: Some code is needed as @MichaelRandall mentioned. Also you want to look into if the data provider is actually thread-safe.

Comment: I added some codesamples in the question. I hope this will help to understand my problem.

Comment: @Michael Randall Activated means that the data from the database is fetchted, too. To activate an additional database we add an connection string to the app.config.

Comment: All of that I/O work is *screaming* to be async these days but I don't know if that's supported by the Oracle provider.

Comment: I am quite sure that  `FetchQueueEntryData(queueItem, conn)` cannot be thread-safe. This (Parallel) code  could fail on you at any time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman please elaborate.

Comment: Elaborate on what?  Post  FetchQueueEntryData first if you really want to discuss this. But a `conn(ection)` shouldn't be shared between threads.